# Apply rewards to products Magento 2 EE

Tags: magento2, checkout, discount, reward-points, reward

I need to apply the reward points discount to the products and not to the subtotal as I need to calculate the tax after all discounts, includying reward points applied value.

[image]

How can I do that?

**Note:** The coupons work as I need, but I have not been able to replicate it in the reward points.

[image]

Comment: I suppose your reward points are from an 3rd party extension. Please visit the configuration and review the condition applying the rule to the product catalog only. The one I have on my marktplace has a condition to apply to product price + (tax, total, etc)

Comment: Hi @MarconyMonteiro
No, I use Magento reward points, I don't use extensions for this